# Convert list elements into successive tuple using python

Tags: python, arrays, list, slice

`a = [0, 18, 27, 43, 52, 65]`

is the list of indices from which I want to access bigger list slicing with

`[0:18],[18:27],[27:43],[43:52], [52:65], [65:]`

How to do it?

I have tried but i not get correct format

`slicing = [index for index in (a[:-1])]`

but that gives me `[0, 18, 27, 43, 52]`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
a = [0, 18, 27, 43, 52, 65]    
res = [bigger_list[x:y] for x, y in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])]
```

and finally, extend it:

```
res.extend(bigger_list[a[-1]:])
```

---

Or to do it in a single line:

```
res = [bigger_list[x:y] for x, y in zip(a[:-1], a[1:])] + bigger_list[a[-1]:]
```

Comment: The last index, `[65:]`, should probably be added as well.

Comment: You dont need to chop the last element, zip will stop after the shortest list

Answer (score 0):

After some tweaking and searching I found answer:

```
res = [bigger_list[i: a[ind+1]] for ind,i in enumerate(a[:-1])]
```

that also gives me `slicing of bigger_list`.